# ASP.NET Core 5 error “An error occurred while processing your request”

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have published my site made in ASP.NET Core 5 (Visual Studio) in a local folder and I registered it in the Administrator (IIS) I also changed the permissions for the IIS_IUSRS user, however it triggers the following error:

[image]

Why this error?

Compiled site:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1Y-lgQbmjHJa3J5SSx4uIlQsgL-xHKD3Q

Comment: The error page gives a really helpful suggestion - activate development mode by setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. This will give you a lot more detail about the error - either enough detail for you to figure out what the problem is, or enough detail you can ask a new question here. Hope that helps :)

Comment: You can try to clear the cookies and cache for your browser and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

1. I Have solved this problem after causing me sleepless nights for a month.
   Go to the folder which you have published your project and look for a folder called Logs

[image]

2. Open the logs folder and check for the following Error, its complaining of appool not added in your respective database

[image]

3. open your SQL server database expend security and right click Logins and select new login.

[image]

4. Enter the Name of the appool that the error on logs is showing and click OK

[image]

5. Go to the login appool that you have just added and right click and choose properties which will open a new window the select user mappings

[image]

6. check your database and two permissions db_datareader and db_datawriter and click ok. Now your application should be working like magic!

Answer (score 0):

If you receive this error while making a project with MVC, the problem will be solved if you update your database from the Package Manager Console section.